# Add Namespace to Each Tag in my XML using Powershell script

Tags: xml, powershell

This is my Xml.I want to add namespace ns33: to every tag in my xml.I want to achieve this using powershell Script.

```Windowspowershell
    <Information>
    <Name>Laksh</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Role>Dev</Role>
    </Information>
```

**This is my Script:**

```
        $Path="C:\Users\Laksh\Random.xml"

        [xml]$XmlData=Get-Content $Path

        $Display=$XmlData.Innerxml.Replace("<","<ns33:")
        $Display=$XmlData.Innerxml.Replace("<ns33:/","</ns33:")

        $Display > "C:\Users\Laksh\result.xml"
```

But the output i expect is:

```Windowspowershell
    <ns33:Information>
    <ns33:name>Laksh</ns33:name>
    <ns33:Age>23</ns33:Age>
    <ns33:Role>Dev</ns33:Role>
    </ns33:Information>
```

Please help me crack This.

Comment: what is the output you are getting? it seems you could be doing the 2nd replace on the same string twice, instead of doing it on the result of the 1st replace

Comment: `ns33` isn't a namespace. It's a namespace *prefix*. It only has *meaning* if  there's a corresponding namespace declaration in *that particular piece of XML*. I'd strongly suggest *not* trying to work with XML via string manipulation and instead learning about how XML works and then using XML tools to generate well-formed XML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace does not replace on the original string. However the return value of `.Replace` contains the result. In your code you assign the result of replace to `$Display` but instead of executing 2nd replace on the result (i.e. `Display`), you are again replacing on original string. The original string does not contain `<ns33:/`, so nothing gets replaced.

You can fix your problem using the following code.

```
[xml]$XmlData=Get-Content $Path

$Display=$XmlData.Innerxml.Replace("<","<ns33:").Replace("<ns33:/","</ns33:")

$Display > "C:\Users\Laksh\result.xml"
```

Comment: Don't ever use string replace functions (or regex) on XML. This is a dangerous and fundamentally wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Convert-ToXmlWithPrefixes
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $InputPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $OutputPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Prefix,
        [Switch]
        $OmitXmlDeclaration
    )

    process
    {
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Xml.Linq') | Out-Null
        $ns33 = [Xml.Linq.XNamespace]$Prefix
        $document = [Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($InputPath)
        $document.Root.Add((New-Object Xml.Linq.XAttribute(([Xml.Linq.XName]([Xml.Linq.XNamespace]::Xmlns + $Prefix)), $Prefix)))

        foreach ($node in $document.Descendants())
        {
            $node.Name = $ns33.GetName($node.Name.LocalName)
        }

        try
        {
            $writerSettings = New-Object Xml.XmlWriterSettings
            $writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $OmitXmlDeclaration
            $writerSettings.Indent = $true
            $writer = [Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($OutputPath, $writerSettings)
            $document.Save($writer)
        }
        finally
        {
            $writer.Dispose()
        }
    }
}

Convert-ToXmlWithPrefixes -InputPath 'C:\Deployment\test.xml' -OutputPath 'C:\Deployment\test_out.xml' -Prefix 'ns33' -OmitXmlDeclaration
```

Input:

```
<Information>
    <Name>Laksh</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Role>Dev</Role>
</Information>
```

Output:

```
<ns33:Information xmlns:ns33="ns33">
  <ns33:Name>Laksh</ns33:Name>
  <ns33:Age>23</ns33:Age>
  <ns33:Role>Dev</ns33:Role>
</ns33:Information>
```

Comment: Is there a special reason to do this with Linq, or just preference?

Comment: In my opinion using some XML API is better approach than text processing. The easiest API I known is Linq.